# After Script runs, Must press Escape key to continue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have a simple macro in Google that ends with the line of code below:

`spreadsheet.getRange('D4').activate();`

The macro simply adds a new row and leaves the pointer to where I want the user to continue. However, after the macro runs, you must either hit the escape key or point to another cell before editing the cell. I cannot figure out how to get the macro to do this so that the user can simply start typing data into the cell. The user may be a novice and may not know how to get out of the apparently frozen situation.

I am not experienced with macros. I only use what I can record. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. What browser are you using? Try adding `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` as the last line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function runOne() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getActiveCell();
  sh.insertRowAfter(rg.getRow());
  rg.offset(1,0).activate();
}
```